# Would someone have an Excel list of at least 20’000 most frequent Russian lemmas with part of speech based on a large and modern corpus?

Tags: resources, word

For non-commercial purposes (personal research), I have researched the resources freely available on Internet and have found lists that did not contain lemmas with part of speech or were based upon rather old or light corpuses distorting significantly frequencies in various dimensions. Would someone know of an updated extended list of Russian lemmas with part of speech based upon a modern and large enough corpus?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a lot of data from [The National Corpus of the Russian Language](https://ruscorpora.ru/new/index.html)

For example, this page contains archives with frequencies of word forms and word combinations, which can be easily transferred to Excel files:

https://ruscorpora.ru/new/corpora-freq.html

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately these frequency list are not aggregated by lemmas and they are missing Part of Speech (POS) identifier. Would you know of another resources by lemmas and with POS ?

Comment: At least, just a large list aggregated by lemmas would be extremely helpful. Thank you again,

Comment: Thank you @Crantisz. Unfortunately, the lists referred to are not aggregated by lemmas. Would you know of a list aggregated by lemmas please ?